# MySQL: is column data safely deleted from hard drive on update/delete?

Tags: mysql, innodb, privacy, erase

Suppose I have one table called 'privacy':

```
privacy (id INT PRIMARY KEY, data BINARY(512))
```

Suppose I insert one row in such table:

```
INSERT INTO privacy(1, 'CIPHERTEXT')
```

with CIPHERTEXT the pseudo random bytes result of an AES encryption of certain plaintext.

My concern comes when UPDATING the `data` column or DELETING such row: Indeed, for privacy reasons, I don't want that someone who access my server retreive erased `data` values.

Does MySQL really delete the previous data from the hard drive when UPDATE/DELETE commands are sent ? Must we UPDATE the row with random data before DELETE command execution ?

Note: my server use an SSD hard drive with TRIM enabled and tables engines are InnoDB.

Thanks.

Comment: if it's an ssd, then you have NO way of knowing if the data has been deleted at all. The wear levelling algorithms may choose to copy the old block to a new one, leaving the original sensitive data in the old block until such time as the drive can clean it up. and mysql may not update the data files to remove old records either. it'll just mark that area as available for re-use.

Comment: The data is not accessible through the database.  I am not aware of any guarantees in MySQL of erasing the data from dirty pages on the drive.  I do think that some commercial databases have options for this functionality.  In addition, the old values may be available in the log files (or the blocks used for the log files) for a long time.

Comment: As an added side note, swapping out to conventional hard drives wouldn't work either, as there's numerous ways to retrieve data from a conventional hard drive as well.  REALLY scrubbing data from a system isn't very trivial, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks all for such info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When InnoDB updates a record there are two paths possible:

1. if new record size is the same (which the case for your table btw) then the new record is written at the same position as the old one. I.e. the new record overwrites the old one.
2. If record size is different then the new record is added to the end
   of used data and the old record is marked as deleted. Take into
   account the old record in both cases is copied to rollback segment.
   See however Marc B's comment - there is no guarantee the new record
   is written at the same physical position on disk.

When InnoDB deletes a record, it's not deleted actually - the record is marked as free. The deleted record may stay in a page for a while until B+ tree is rebalanced (read - a lot of records are inserted or deleted).

Having said that your old record is recoverable with high chance of success no matter what you do.